# Referencing for mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i'm currently trying to reference a collection called items with the structure below

```
packageSchema = schema({
                recipient: String,
                contents: [{item :{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'items', required : true}, amount: String}]
```

Below is my code for getting one package via its id

```
   getOnePackage : function(id,callback)
{
    packageModel.findById(id,callback)
    .populate('contents')
}
```

So when i call the above function i'm expecting to get this result

```
{
   recipient : Dave
   contents : [
      {item : {
        _id:5d2b0c444a3cc6438a7b98ae,
        itemname : "Statue",
        description : "A statue of Avery"
      } ,amount : "2"},
      {item : {
        _id:5d25ad29e601ef2764100b94,
        itemname : "Sugar Pack",
        description : "Premium Grade Sugar From China"
      } ,amount : "5"},
   ]
}
```

But what i got from testing in Postman is this :

```
{
 recipient : Dave,
 contents : []
}
```

May i know where did it went wrong? And also how do i prevent mongoose from automatically insert an objectId for every single element in the contents array....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because element in `contents` array is object with `item` field so your populate should be:

```
.populate('contents.item')
```

Comment: Tks :),it worked like a charm,also apologies for the late reply